# sh shell redirecting a subshell to file, can't find the right syntax

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, subshell

i want to run a sed command with programatically with changing parameters.
the thing is that i cant find the correct syntax to do so.
i want to configure a conf file with this and
change a dir path to another.

i'm currently using:

```
RESULT=$("sed 's/--ROOT_DIR--/${root_inst_dir}/g' ${root_inst_dir}/${tool_name}/etc/${tool_name}.conf > ${SOURCE_DIR}/${tool_name}.conf")
```

and i get the error message:

```
./change_tst.sh: line 7: sed 's/--ROOT_DIR--//home/test_dir/g' /home/tst/conf.conf > /home/script_tst/conf.conf: No such file or directory
```

the ">" is not working for some reason.

what am i doing wrong? or what is the best way to do this ?

**UPDATE**

i drooped the result variable and now running this:

```
(sed 's/--ROOT_DIR--/$root_inst_dir/g' ${root_inst_dir}/${tool_name}/etc/${tool_name}.conf) > ${SOURCE_DIR}/${tool_name}.conf
```

the new file is being created in > ${SOURCE_DIR}/${tool_name}.conf,
but the search/replace is happening literally and not as a variable...

thanks.

Comment: it's there :) double checked. and even if not, it should create it, but it's definitely there

Comment: I think directory script_tst not exist

Comment: What are you hoping to store in `RESULT`? The output of the sed command or its exit status or something else? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: the output of the sed command should be redirected to the file via">" , in the result i expect to get the exit status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting `"` inside parenthesis will result in bash wanting to execute a command named exactly:

```
sed 's/--ROOT_DIR--/${root_inst_dir}/g' ${root_inst_dir}/${tool_name}/etc/${tool_name}.conf > ${SOURCE_DIR}/${tool_name}.conf"
```

Such command does not exist on your system. 
Probably you intended to put `"` outside `$(...)`:

```
RESULT="$(sed 's/--ROOT_DIR--/${root_inst_dir}/g' ${root_inst_dir}/${tool_name}/etc/${tool_name}.conf > ${SOURCE_DIR}/${tool_name}.conf)"
```

Better way, if you don't need the RESULT variable and if you want to properly escape `root_inst_dir` variable:

```
sed 's#--ROOT_DIR--#'"${root_inst_dir}"'#g' "${root_inst_dir}/${tool_name}/etc/${tool_name}.conf" > "${SOURCE_DIR}/${tool_name}.conf"
```

Or if you need RESULT variable:

```
sed 's#--ROOT_DIR--#'"${root_inst_dir}"'#g' "${root_inst_dir}/${tool_name}/etc/${tool_name}.conf" > "${SOURCE_DIR}/${tool_name}.conf"
RESULT=$(cat ${SOURCE_DIR}/${tool_name}.conf)
```

Comment: Note that there is absolutely no reason to ever write `RESULT="$(cmd > redirected)"`, since it is guaranteed to assign the empty string to RESULT.  You might as well write `RESULT=""; cmd > redirected;`!

Comment: You could do `RESULT=$(cmd | tee redirected)` - although I don't think that's a better than what's suggested in this answer

Comment: hi, i can live without the result, but your examples dont work, i tried: (sed 's/--ROOT_DIR--/$root_inst_dir/g' ${root_inst_dir}/${tool_name}/etc/${tool_name}.conf) > ${SOURCE_DIR}/${tool_name}.conf , this works but the /search/replace value inside the ' ' is taken literally and not as a variable... how can i escape the var inside  '' ?

Comment: Strings inside `'` are taken literally. If you want variables to expand, use double qoutation marks `"`. And why do you need braces? I would write: `sed 's/--ROOT_DIR--/'"$root_inst_dir"'/g' "${root_inst_dir}/${tool_name}/etc/${tool_name}.conf" > "${SOURCE_DIR}/${tool_name}.conf"`

Comment: @KamilCuk then i get this: sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'... and the sed command needs the '

Comment: If the variable `root_inst_dir` contains `/` characters it gets parsed by sed utility as command separator. Try using `#` as separator, like `sed 's#--ROOT_DIR--#'"$root_inst_dir"'#g'` (and make sure the variable root_inst_dir does not contain any `#` characters. If it does,t hey need to be escaped for sed utility to work)

Comment: @KamilCuk, you are my hero :) thank you very much... update this comment on your answer, and ill mark it as the one. thanks again !